# How to add Logo, button image and button menu to Firefox toolbar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm using XUL to write my firefox toolbar. I use that xul code to do simple label button:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="Sample"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"><script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://sample/content/sample.js" />
<toolbox id="toolbox">
   <toolbar id="Sample" toolbarname="Sample" >
       <label value="Lable Button "/>
   </toolbar>
</toolbox>
</overlay>
```

My question is how to add logo image, image button and button menu...also how to add submenu. Please somebody submit a quick sample of code, so I will understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there isn't a button - it is a [static label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/label).

To add a logo use [`image` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/image) (see example in the documentation).

To add an image button use [`toolbarbutton` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbarbutton) (see example in the documentation).

To add a submenu use [`toolbarbutton` tag with `type="menu"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbarbutton#a-toolbarbutton.type) and put a `menupopup` tag inside (again, there is an example in the documentation).

*Note*: You can use `src` attribute to specify the image source for an `image` element and `image` attribute to specify the image source for a `toolbarbutton` element. However, it is preferable to set the images in CSS, you can use [`list-style-image` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-image) for that:

```css
#myToolbarButton
{
  list-style-image: url(chrome://myextension/skin/toolbar.png);
}
```